# How to config a custom domain from godaddy in aws amplify for web app and google for email?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, gmail, custom-domain, aws-route53

I bougth a domain in godaddy, setup the email host in google and was working fine, but yesterday config aws amplify and route53 with with the custom domain to access a web page and the email just can't receive emails, only send, i can't figure out why it stopped working when aws was configured and can't make it work again.

I tried adding the gmail MX records to aws route53 but still not working